# SharePoint 2013: Promoted Links Wrap Tiles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, css

We have implemented a solution to wrap tiles within promoted links as described in the following article:

[SharePoint 2013: Promoted Links Wrap Tiles](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19622.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-wrap-tiles.aspx)

This works well for us however now we want to make use of multiple promoted link lists. On the technet page someone already asks for the same thing that we need however there is no answer yet. I noticed that we get the same web part ID as guy that has the same request, being: WebPartWPQ4.

Going trough the script myself i figured that i need to modify the line that finds the promoted links items:

```
var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-  root').length;
```

I tried to modify it like this:

```
var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('#WebPartWPQ4 > .ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root').length;
```

However that doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps this question would get better results on stack overflow, however im not sure where exactly this belongs.